# Clarification on AUTOSAR BswMLinScheduleIndication container

Tags: automotive

I didn't manage to understand content of AUTOSAR BswMLinScheduleIndication container. This container should configure mode request ports associated with BswM_LinSM_CurrentSchedule API function. The issue is the meaning of BswMLinScheduleRef parameter.

From AUTOSAR Guide to Mode Management I got the impression, that current schedule table should be the mode value, but then why it is mentioned in BswMLinScheduleIndication container? If both BswMLinScheduleRef and BswMLinSMChannelRef serve as mode request source description, then what is the value of BswMLinScheduleIndication?

Comment: Did your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427017/explanation-of-autosar-bswmlinscheduleindication-container-content) on stack overflow not receive sufficient attention? How much of this question is repeated from the previous question? Link what documents you have found that might give some help to people answering.

Comment: Yes, this is the repetition of my previous question. I have tried to ask it here, thinking that probability to get an answer here is higher. My question is based on this specification https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-3/AUTOSAR_SWS_BSWModeManager.pdf.  Unfortunately this topic is not covered in explanatory document https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-3/AUTOSAR_EXP_ModeManagementGuide.pdf

Comment: Cross-posting is not seen as good on stack exchange.